# In Network programmation what happens if If the sender writes a byte and then does nothing else

Tags: sockets, server, client, byte, buffer

I would like to answer this question empirically and theoretically :

If the sender writes a byte and then does nothing else (neither reads nor writes to the socket), for one minute... .

1. Will this byte be sent to the reader on its own?
2. Or will the system wait until it has enough to fill a segment?

I did the test between a server and a client but I am not sure about the result

[image]

What I understand it has to do with the buffer but I don't understand why.

Here are my serveur code and client code :

```html
/*
client.c

Se connecter a un serveur qui calcule 3n+1
*/
# include "sys.h"

/* travail  --  dialogue avec le serveur */
void travail(FILE * stream)
{
    system("date") ;
    fprintf(stream, "let's go \n") ;

    int lu= fgetc(stream) ;
    while (lu)
    {
        printf("charcater read: %c\n", lu) ;
        system("date") ;
        lu= fgetc(stream) ;
    }
}

int main(int ac, char * av[])
{
    int t ;
    FILE * stream ;

    t= dial("localhost", "19986") ;
    if (t < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Pas moyen d'appeler %s\n", "localhost") ;
        exit(1) ;
    }

    stream= fdopen(t, "r+") ;
    if (stream == 0)
    {
        perror("fdopen") ;
        exit(1) ;
    }

    /* pas de buffer */
    setbuf(stream, 0) ;

    travail(stream) ;

    fprintf(stream, "QUIT\n") ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

```html
/*
serveur.c

Faire tourner une fois 3n+1
*/
# include "sys.h"
# include <unistd.h>

int servir(int fd)
{
    FILE * stream ;
    char buffer[100] ;

    stream= fdopen(fd, "r+") ;
    if (stream == 0)
    {
        perror("serveur fdopen") ;
        exit(1) ;
    }
    setbuf(stream, 0) ;

    fgets (buffer, sizeof buffer, stream) ;
    if (!strcmp(buffer, "c'est partie\n"))
    {
        puts("J'ai recu le code : pouet, j'envoie un 'a' et c'est tout") ;
        fprintf(stream, "a") ;
        system("date") ;
        puts("J'ai envoyé le 'a', je vais dormir 60 secondes") ;
        system("sleep 60") ;
    }
    
    exit(0) ;
}

int main(int ac, char * av[])
{
    char * p ;

    p= answer("19986", servir) ;
    fprintf(stderr, "repondre a echoue: %s\n", p) ;
    return 1 ;
}
```

```html
/* sys.h
Inclure
 */
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/socket.h>
# include <netinet/in.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <netdb.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <ctype.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <signal.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <assert.h>

int dial(char * host, char * port);          // dans dial.c
char * answer(char * port, int (*fun)(int)); // dans answer.c
```

Comment: The byte will be sent. In the case of TCP there will be a delay due to the Nagle algorithm unless `TCP_NODELAY` is in effect.

Comment: how can I demonstrate that with a simple execution between a server and a client ?

Comment: Fix your code. `fgetc()` returns EOF at end of stream, not zero.